# Android Uri permissions expiry

Tags: android

On Android 11 once the user selects his files via OPEN_DOCUMENT with read and write flags, I upload the content uri to a room db after taking the permissions over restart.
Later when I use these URIs on a foreground task after few uploads I get error about no permission granted
Ex: out of 1000 images, I face this error once I reach 500 images

Can someone help me to understand permissions granted in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 and higher, [you are limited to 512 permission grants](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149315521#comment7). On older devices, [you are limited to 128 permission grants](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149315521).

You are going to need to find ways to need fewer permission grants. For example, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to let a user grant you permission for a whole tree, rather than needing permission grants for individual documents.

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround, I couldn't find this in the Android docs hence the question. Thanks once again